# Web App Restore - What does "Ignore Conflicting Host Names on Restore" do?

Tags: azure, restore, azure-web-app-service

As seen in the following image: [Restore Backup Advanced Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPccf.png), when restoring an Azure Web App, we are given the option to "Ignore Conflicting Host Names on Restore".

I find this to be ambiguous.

By allowing restoring of a site that has conflicting hostnames, which of the following is it saying? Or is it implying something else?

- The hostnames in the backup will be applied to the restored site, but the site will be left inactive, or
- The hostnames in the backup will be ignored and the web app will be restored with no hostnames

Comment: This will simply allow backup if you have multiple Web App running in single subscription and has conflicting hostnames if you don't allow then the backup will not be proceeded if you have conflicting hostnames between Web Apps

Comment: I assume that you mean "restore" where you've said "backup". The question is "what will happen to the hostnames on the app that is being restored if I do specify that I want the conflicting hostnames ignored", not "what will happen if there are conflicting hostnames and I specify that I do not want them ignored"

Comment: hostnames will not be added with restore in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The hostnames in the backup will be ignored and the web app will be restored with no hostnames

This is true.

The option `Ignore Conflicting Host Names on Restore`
 is to set a logic when restoring an app with custom domains.

Custom domains are added to the app when it is being restored. If you set it to **No**, it might fail due to conflicts during the operation. If you set it to **Yes**, it will remove custom domains automatically when restoring the app successfully.

You could refer to [Azure SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.models.restorerequestinner.ignoreconflictinghostnames?view=azure-dotnet) for more detalis.